Is there a way to show in the taskbar that a Windows Explorer window has multiple tabs?
Let's say I have in Windows Explorer these windows with these tab names:

"tab A"
"tab B"
"tab C" + "tab D", and the active one is "tab D"
"tab E"

In this case the taskbar will show:

"tab A"
"tab B"
"tab D"
"tab E"

So I'll be searching "tab C" and not finding it (the icon is also the same for single-tab windows and multiple-tab windows: the usual yellow folder icon)
Is there a way to show a different icon for multiple-tab windows, or perhaps a way to display the names of all tabs? (instead of "tab D", it could show "tab C, tab D")

Is there a reason you don't want all tabs in the same window? that would instantly solve the searching problem

Yes, I group them by different tasks, one window for each task

What about WIN+TAB? Shows you all individual tabs, you can click the right one and it switches to the grouped one?
